# Hibernate Criteria - multiple entity types in projection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two entities `Category`, `Subscriber`. `Subscriber` has reference on `Category` (there can be only one subscriber for given category i.e. 1-to-1). In HQL I'm able to select all categories and it's subscriber (if any) by using `LEFT JOIN` (projection: category, nullable subscriber i.e. `SELECT category, subscriber`).

I would like to rewrite this to `Criteria`. Since I can navigate only from `Subscriber` to `Category` I have to use `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
 Criteria c = getSession()
            .createCriteria(Subscriber.class, subscriberAlias)
            .createAlias("category", JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

This way result set contains only `Category`. How can I add `Subscriber` in `Criteria` projection?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is entity graphs.

https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/

The link above gives an example of in jpa 2.1 but by the code you have provided it looks like you are on hibernate 4. Maybe it is time to upgrade if you have the luxury.